# Scrapping local events from Google events

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm attempting to scrape all of the events listed on Google for a specific time period. While my code works to some extent, I am only able to gather 20 items out of 50 or more. Even though I am using a scroll to view command, it only grabs 20 items. What am I missing in gathering all of the elements on the page?
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

chrome_driver_path = "/Development/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

website = "https://www.google.com/search?q=charlotte+nc&ei=6ObaYqueDfWrqtsPsP2MuAs&uact=5&oq=events&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEEMyCggAELEDEIMBEEMyCggAELEDEMkDEEMyBQgAEJIDMgUIABCSAzILCAAQgAQQsQMQgwEyBAgAEEMyBQgAEIAEMgcIABCxAxBDMgoIABCxAxCDARBDOgoILhDHARDRAxBDOhAILhCxAxCDARDHARDRAxBDOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoICC4QgAQQsQNKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQAFjGBWCMB2gAcAF4AIABkwGIAYUGkgEDMS41mAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ibp=htl;events&rciv=evn&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjV8dWAi435AhWenWoFHU5-BxAQ8eoFKAJ6BAgDEA8#fpstate=tldetail&htichips=date:week&htischips=&htivrt=events&htidocid=L2F1dGhvcml0eS9ob3Jpem9uL2NsdXN0ZXJlZF9ldmVudC8yMDIyLTA3LTI0fDE3NTc3NDU4NDA4OTA0MDcxMDk2"
driver.get(website)
sleep(2)


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@jsname='SJ2nIb'][4]").click()
sleep(1)

for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='YOGjf' and @role='heading']"):

    try:
        x.click()
    except:
        pass
    sleep(2)
    try:
        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='Hc1J4e']//div[@class='dEuIWb']").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='Hc1J4e']//div[@class='dEuIWb Nre7t']").text

    try:
        times = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='Hc1J4e']//div[@class='Gkoz3']").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        times = ""
        print(name,"no times")
    try:
        address = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='Hc1J4e']//span[@class='U6txu']").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        address = ""
        print(name,"no addy")
    try:
        description = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='Hc1J4e']//span[@class='PVlUWc']").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        description = ""
        print(name,"no description")
    try:
        tickets = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='Hc1J4e']//a[@class='uaYYHd vQQnKe uMdbSb']").get_attribute("href")
    except:
        tickets = ""
        print(name,"no tickets")
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', x)
    print(name, times, address, description, tickets)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to scroll down the page to make other items visible before you extract them. I have added code for infinite scrolling as shown below. It works for me after making that change.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

chrome_driver_path = "/Development/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)


website = "https://www.google.com/search?q=charlotte+nc&ei=6ObaYqueDfWrqtsPsP2MuAs&uact=5&oq=events&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEEMyCggAELEDEIMBEEMyCggAELEDEMkDEEMyBQgAEJIDMgUIABCSAzILCAAQgAQQsQMQgwEyBAgAEEMyBQgAEIAEMgcIABCxAxBDMgoIABCxAxCDARBDOgoILhDHARDRAxBDOhAILhCxAxCDARDHARDRAxBDOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoICC4QgAQQsQNKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQAFjGBWCMB2gAcAF4AIABkwGIAYUGkgEDMS41mAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ibp=htl;events&rciv=evn&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjV8dWAi435AhWenWoFHU5-BxAQ8eoFKAJ6BAgDEA8#fpstate=tldetail&htichips=date:week&htischips=&htivrt=events&htidocid=L2F1dGhvcml0eS9ob3Jpem9uL2NsdXN0ZXJlZF9ldmVudC8yMDIyLTA3LTI0fDE3NTc3NDU4NDA4OTA0MDcxMDk2"
driver.get(website)
sleep(2)


driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@jsname='SJ2nIb'][4]").click()
sleep(1)

last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(3)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='YOGjf' and @role='heading']"):

    try:
        x.click()
    except:
        pass
    sleep(2)
    try:
        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='Hc1J4e']//div[@class='dEuIWb']").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='Hc1J4e']//div[@class='dEuIWb Nre7t']").text

    try:
        times = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='Hc1J4e']//div[@class='Gkoz3']").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        times = ""
        print(name,"no times")
    try:
        address = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='Hc1J4e']//span[@class='U6txu']").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        address = ""
        print(name,"no addy")
    try:
        description = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='Hc1J4e']//span[@class='PVlUWc']").text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        description = ""
        print(name,"no description")
    try:
        tickets = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='Hc1J4e']//a[@class='uaYYHd vQQnKe uMdbSb']").get_attribute("href")
    except:
        tickets = ""
        print(name,"no tickets")
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', x)
    print(name, times, address, description, tickets)
```